# Cocos2d-x v3: ClippingNode not working on RenderTexture

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

If a ClippingNode is rendered to a RenderTexture rather than being added as child (or in my case added to a container which is itself rendered to a RenderTexture), the effect is broken:

The sprite is not masked (the stencil has no effect), and all the rest of the screen is filled with white colour (in the case where the ClippingNode is added on top of all other layers).

(Tested on ios and win32)

```
auto stencil = DrawNode::create();
static Point triangle[3];
triangle[0] = Point(-40, -40);
triangle[1] = Point(40, -40);
triangle[2] = Point(0, 40);
static Color4F green(0, 1, 0, 1);
stencil->drawPolygon(triangle, 3, green, 0, green);

auto clipper = ClippingNode::create();
clipper->setAnchorPoint(Point(0.5, 0.5));
clipper->setPosition( Point(100, 100) );
clipper->setStencil(stencil);
clipper->setInverted(true);

// containerAddedAsChild->addChild(clipper, 20);      // this works fine
containerRenderedToTexture->addChild(clipper, 20);    // this breaks 

auto img = Sprite::create("test_sprite.png");
img->setAnchorPoint(Point(0.5, 0.5));
clipper->addChild(img);
```

How can I get a ClippingNode working on a RenderTexture with the intended result (the result you get when adding the ClippingNode as a child rather than using a RenderTexture)? Thanks.

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: Added a question to my post.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking, but you can get ClippingNodes to render correctly onto your RenderTexture by making sure to set the depth stencil option.

In Cocos2d-x 3.x it looks like this:

```
RenderTexture* renderTexture = RenderTexture::create(paddedSize.width, paddedSize.height,
    Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGBA8888,
    GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES); // configure for clipping node

renderTexture->beginWithClear(0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f);
clippingNode->Node::visit();
renderTexture->end();
```

In Cocos2d-iPhone / Swift 3.x it looks like this:

```
CCRenderTexture *renderTexture = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:paddedSize.width height:paddedSize.height
    pixelFormat:CCTexturePixelFormat_RGBA8888
    depthStencilFormat:GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES];
[renderTexture beginWithClear:0.0f g:0.0f b:0.0f a:0.0f depth:1.0f];
[clippingNode visit];
[renderTexture end];
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work myself, where the clipping node works fine on the child sprite, but if I want to render it to a texture, calling `Node::visit()` from the clipping node or the sprite within it doesn't do anything. It's like its invisible on the render texture. I'm creating the renderTexture with  `CC_GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` but that seems like a macro for the same thing

Comment: nevermind, the issue was that I was hiding the sprite after the `end()` call and that the issue, along with the size of the RT being too small because the position of the sprite put it off screen.